# Remove empty directories

Tags: windows, command-line

I found this command on this site for recursively removing empty directories, but was unable to comment to ask this question since I just registered and have zero rep.......

```
for /f "delims=" %d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%d"
```

I'm hesitant to run it on a server (worked great in a test directory on my Win7 laptop).....I ran it inside the directory I wanted it to start in.  Should I just run it inside the directory it should recursively check or is there a way to set the start point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To start the command in a different directory

```
for /f "delims=" %d in ('dir c:\pathtostart /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%d"
```

and change `c:\pathtostart` as appropriate.

---

#### To use a batch file

Alternatively create a batch file `RemoveEmptyDirs.cmd`:

```
@echo off 
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir %1 /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d"
```

and call as follows:

```
RemoveEmptyDirs c:\pathtostart
```

---

#### To test before removing

If you are hesitent then to test what will happen replace `rd` with `echo`.
This will echo the list of directories that would be removed.

When you a happy with the list replace the `echo` with `rd` and run the deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dir "%~1"`. This will handle quoted paths as well, in case you want to start in a directory which contains spaces (`RemoveEmptyDirs "C:\program files"`).